# Remove navigation header on screen for react native app

Tags: react-native

I want to remove header from my screen where I use bottom tab navigator.

Here is code example:

```
export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <ProductList />;
  }
}

export class Settings extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Chat />;
  }
}

const Main = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,
  },
});
```

navigationOptions for header seams to be ignored

```
 navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
```

But when I use navigation option on single page without createBottomTabNavigator it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> You can use this instead of above

```
    export class Home extends Component {
       static navigationOptions = {
            header: {
              visible: false,
            }
          }
      render() {
        return <ProductList />;
      }
    }

    export class Settings extends Component {
      render() {
        return <Chat />;
      }
    }

    const Main = createBottomTabNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: Home
      },
      Settings: {
        screen: Settings,
      },
    }, 
    { 
        headerMode: 'screen' 
    });
```

> Hope this will help you

Comment: Where should I add this?

Comment: where you want to hide header!

Comment: above `render` method you can add that static methods!

Comment: You mean something like this:

export class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: {
      visible: false,
    },
  };
  render() {
    return <ProductList />;
  }
}

Comment: The only thing that happens is that header on bottomnavbar is smaller, but navigation option on top of screen is still there :(